# SQL Server stored procedures and permissions with other databases

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, stored-procedures, permissions

I am configuring the database accounts for some new users. I have come up with the following solution which is 99% of the way to getting the accounts to work but I have hit a problem which I cannot resolve.

Firstly, I created a new login with SQL Server authentication and then gave them the `EXECUTE` permission to all stored procedures. This allows them to run them all but they cannot view the code and they cannot view the database tables.

Inside the stored procedures I added the following:

```
WITH EXEC AS OWNER
```

This allowed the stored procedures to run as the default account we normally use and this has the role of `db_owner`. This allows the new users to run all the stored procedures and it works great until I hit the following problem:

Some of the stored procedures (all of which are using dynamic SQL) call some synonyms which link to tables in two other databases (history and a data mart database). This gives me the following error:

> The server principal "{username}" is not able to access the database "{database name}" under the current security context.

The account which I am using in the `WITH EXEC AS` is the `db_owner` of all three databases I am working with.

What can I do to resolve this problem? Many thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`EXECUTE AS Owner` is a database sandbox. Think about it, it **has** to be. Otherwise a *database* administrator can issue and `EXECUTE AS USER = 'somesystemadmin'` and elevate himself to an *instance* level administrator. The details are described in [Extending Database Impersonation by Using EXECUTE AS](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188304%28v=sql.105%29.aspx):

> when impersonating a principal by using the EXECUTE AS USER statement, or within a database-scoped module by using the EXECUTE AS clause, the scope of impersonation is restricted to the database by default. This means that references to objects outside the scope of the database will return an error.

The solution is simple: sign the procedure. See [Call a procedure in another database from an activated procedure](http://rusanu.com/2006/03/07/call-a-procedure-in-another-database-from-an-activated-procedure/) for an example. Read more at [Module Signing](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms345102%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) and [Signing Stored Procedures in SQL Server](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb669102%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

Comment: I noticed the first article you wrote has the following code: ALTER DATABASE [my_database] SET TRUSTWORTHY ON, which appears to set the standard dbo to a sys-admin level, what is your opinion on this? Wouldn't this make the "owner" user effectively an instance manager user like you said? (I haven't tried it yet by the way)

Comment: `TRUSTWORTHY` works too, is much simpler as signing, but only if you fully understand and agree with the security consequences (ie. all members of `db_owner` are de facto `sysadmin`). My opinion would be to spend a bit of effort to get the signature working. Then you can make an informed decision which to use.

Comment: Thank you for your help, you are a life saver! I will look through the signing as you are right, it is better to do the "correct" thing and I always try to. I have put trustworthy for today and I will attempt to add the signature tomorrow. Thank you once again.